# ipvsadmのテーブルを設定してもOSを再起動すると戻ってしまう

Tags: linux

### 概要

ipvsadmのテーブルを設定し、サービスの再起動では設定情報をクリアーしてリストアできるのですが、OSを再起動するとテーブル情報がリストアされません。
OS再起動後も設定を維持する方法はありますでしょうか。

#### １．バージョン確認

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
Rocky Linux release 8.7 (Green Obsidian)

# yum list installed | grep ipvsadm
ipvsadm.x86_64                       1.31-1.el8                             @appstream

# yum list installed | grep keepalived
keepalived.x86_64                    2.1.5-9.el8                            @appstream
```

#### ２．サービスの状態確認

```
# systemctl status ipvsadm
● ipvsadm.service - Initialise the Linux Virtual Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ipvsadm.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2022-12-13 11:18:36 JST; 2h 38min ago
```

#### ３．サービススクリプト

```
# less /usr/lib/systemd/system/ipvsadm.service
[Unit]
Description=Initialise the Linux Virtual Server
After=syslog.target network.target 

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "exec /sbin/ipvsadm-restore < /etc/sysconfig/ipvsadm"
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "exec /sbin/ipvsadm-save -n > /etc/sysconfig/ipvsadm"
ExecStop=/sbin/ipvsadm -C
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### ４．テーブル設定を追加

```
# ipvsadm -L
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  192.168.100.100:http sh
  -> 192.168.100.101:http         Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.102:http         Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.103:http         Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.104:http         Route   1      0          0         
TCP  192.168.100.100:https sh
  -> 192.168.100.101:https        Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.102:https        Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.103:https        Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.104:https        Route   1      0          0
```

#### ５．サービス停止 -> ipvsadmテーブルの状態

```
# systemctl stop ipvsadm
# ipvsadm -L
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
```

#### ６．サービス開始 -> ipvsadmテーブルの状態

```
# systemctl start ipvsadm
# ipvsadm -L
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
TCP  192.168.100.100:http sh
  -> 192.168.100.101:http         Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.102:http         Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.103:http         Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.104:http         Route   1      0          0         
TCP  192.168.100.100:https sh
  -> 192.168.100.101:https        Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.102:https        Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.103:https        Route   1      0          0         
  -> 192.168.100.104:https        Route   1      0          0
```

#### ７．OS再起動 -> ipvsadmテーブルの状態

```
# ipvsadm -L
IP Virtual Server version 1.2.1 (size=4096)
Prot LocalAddress:Port Scheduler Flags
  -> RemoteAddress:Port           Forward Weight ActiveConn InActConn
```

#### ８．サービスの起動順序

[image: サービス起動順序]
サービスの起動順序を変更する方法もあるようですが、原因を特定出来ない状態です。
ご教授頂けますと助かります。

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/slsqxbo0njdtn6) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: keepalived がルールを上書きしているのでは？
"systemctl disable keepalived.service" と無効にしてから OS 再起動するとどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。keepalivedのサービスを起動しなければ、ロードバランサのテーブル情報を読み込みました。keepalivedの設定を確認してみます。

Comment: systemdのユニットファイル内にあるkeepalivedの起動スクリプトのオプションにより回避できました。質問をクローズします。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

ipvsadmの起動後にkeepalivedが停止することでIPVS仮想サーバーテーブルからすべてのエントリを削除する処理を行っていたようです。
今回の質問内容の問題点はkeepalivedが停止している状況にありますので、質問をcloseします。